# how to call blob object as file to the asp.net MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, docx, filesaver.js

I successfully downloaded the file with the help of filesaver.js.

```
var out = doc.getZip().generate({
type: "blob",
mimeType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
}) //Output the document using Data-URI
console.log(out);
saveAs(out,"Details.docx");
```

In out console I am getting object which contain size, Type.

How  to save this downloaded file to AWS s3 Bucket by using ASP.NET MVC

how to call the file object to the controller

```
public ContentResult UploadDocument()
    {
        string result = "";
        try
        {
            int fileCount = Request.Files.Count;
            HttpPostedFileBase PostedFile = Request.Files[0];
            string path = "Test" + "_" + PostedFile.FileName;

            using (IAmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(_awsAccessKey, _awsSecretKey, RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
            {
                PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest
                {
                    BucketName = _bucketName,
                    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead,
                    Key = string.Format("FolderName/" + path),
                    InputStream = PostedFile.InputStream
                };
                s3client.PutObject(putObjectRequest);
            }
            result = "Success";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            result = ex.Message;

        }
        
        return Content(result);
    }
```

I am getting Request.Files.Count  null in the controller

Comment: what excactly is your problem? Do you receive an exception? Is the file null?

Comment: Yes I am getting file null